# adamsync.exe /sync is failing with "Naming Violation"

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, .net

I am trying to synchronize my AD LDS instance (localhost:50006) with AD DS entries (basically trying to get user and computer accounts from AD DS so that I can use windows security principals in my LDS instance). I have been following http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770408.aspx and _http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeff/archive/2007/04/01/synchronize-active-directory-to-adam-with-adamsync-step-by-step.aspx to do the sync and got **Ldap error occured. ldap_add_sW: Naming Violation.
Extended Info: 00002099: NameErr: DSID-030510C6, problem 2005 (NAMING_VIOLATION)
, data 0, best match of:
        'CN=Test,DC=COM'**

Any thoughts on how to analyze or debug are really helpful :) (please see below for all the details)

### Update

looks like I need to update schema with posssuperiors ( http://blogs.technet.com/b/efleis/archive/2005/09/14/syncing-to-our-ou-synctargetou-nc-instead.aspx ). I will update you if it works.

**Error detail from log**

```
Processing Entry: Page 1, Frame 1, Entry 48, Count 1, USN 0
Processing source entry <guid=2b4f58a3ba5a3246b1fd59594d2d4c4f>
Processing in-scope entry 2b4f58a3ba5a3246b1fd59594d2d4c4f.
Adding target object CN=Builtin,CN=Test,DC=COM.
Adding attributes: sourceobjectguid, objectClass, instanceType, showInAdvancedViewOnly, creationTime, forceLogoff, lockoutDuration, lockOutObservationWindow, lockoutThreshold, maxPwdAge, minPwdAge, minPwdLength, modifiedCountAtLastProm, nextRid, pwdProperties, pwdHistoryLength, uASCompat, lastagedchange, 
Ldap error occured. ldap_add_sW: Naming Violation. 
Extended Info: 00002099: NameErr: DSID-030510C6, problem 2005 (NAMING_VIOLATION), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=Test,DC=COM'
.
Ldap error occured. ldap_add_sW: Naming Violation. 
Extended Info: 00002099: NameErr: DSID-030510C6, problem 2005 (NAMING_VIOLATION), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=Test,DC=COM'
.
Saving Configuration File on CN=Test,DC=COM

Saved configuration file.
```

**Executed Commands**

```
C:\Windows\ADAM>LDIFDE.EXE -i -u -s localhost:50008 -c "cn=Configuration,dc=X" #
configurationNamingContext -j . -f MS-adamschemaw2k8.LDF
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
.........


C:\Windows\ADAM>LDIFDE.EXE -i -c "cn=Configuration,dc=X" #configurationNamingCon
text -f MS-AdamSyncMetadata.LDF
..........


C:\Windows\ADAM>notepad test.xml

C:\Windows\ADAM>adamsync.exe /install localhost:50008 test.xml
Done.

C:\Windows\ADAM>adamsync.exe /sync localhost:50008 CN=Test,DC=COM
**Ldap error occured. ldap_add_sW: Naming Violation.
Extended Info: 00002099: NameErr: DSID-030510C6, problem 2005 (NAMING_VIOLATION)**
, data 0, best match of:
        'CN=Test,DC=COM'
.
```

I have replaced the entries as mentioned in the articles (please see below for the xml and AD LDS instance setup conf):

```
<configuration>     
  <description>sample Adamsync configuration file</description>     
  <security-mode>object</security-mode>         
  <source-ad-name>mydomain.com</source-ad-name>     
  <source-ad-partition>DC=mydomain,DC=com</source-ad-partition>
  <source-ad-account>domainadminaccount</source-ad-account>                
  <account-domain>mydomain.com</account-domain>
  <target-dn>CN=Test,DC=COM</target-dn>     
  <query>           
   <base-dn>DC=mydomain,DC=com</base-dn>
   <object-filter>(objectClass=*)</object-filter>

Install a unique instance of AD LDS.

Instance name: instance5
Computers will connect to this instance of AD LDS using the following ports:
LDAP port: 50008
SSL port: 50009

AD LDS replication will use Negotiate authentication.

Store AD LDS data files in the following location:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ADAM\instance5\data

Store AD LDS log files in the following location:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ADAM\instance5\data

Run AD LDS using the following account:
NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

Set up the following account to administer AD LDS:
mydomain\domainadminuseraccount

Create the following application directory partition:
CN=Test,DC=COM 

Import these LDIF files:
MS-AdamSyncMetadata.LDF
MS-ADLDS-DisplaySpecifiers.LDF
MS-InetOrgPerson.LDF
MS-User.LDF
MS-UserProxy.LDF
MS-UserProxyFull.LDF
```

Best Regards!